# different IDEs package war differently

Tags: maven, jpa

Added the JPA project facet to a Maven project and configured using Eclipse.  This created a `persistence.xml` under `src/main/java/META-INF`.  Deploy the project and everything is OK.

Save the project to git and another developer attempts to deploy the project using NetBeans.  `SEVERE: FAIL ... example:    Missing required persistence.xml for @PersistenceContext ref "entityManager" to unit "example"`

In NetBeans moving `persistence.xml` to `src/main/resources` and everything is OK.

Is Eclipse creating the `persistence.xml` in the wrong place or is NetBeans failing to package the META-INF into the war?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`src/main/java` is the wrong place for `META-INF`. The java dir is for Java. The resources dir is for resources. META-INF and its XML files are resources.

Anecdotally, I'll also say that "Eclipse broke something and then Netbeans was OK" is oddly familiar to me... :P